# Shrink a range by a specific number of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select the range starting from the active cell down to the next non-blank cell but stopping three cells before the bottom.

If I record a macro with the keyboard sequence Shift-End, Shift-Down, Shift-Up, Shift-Up, Shift-Up the recorded VBA is

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A32").Select
```

The problem is that the length of the range is hard-coded.

If I try

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Resize(numRows - 3, numColumns).Select
```

VBA throws an "Application-defined or object-defined error" (Run-time error '1004') at the Resize line.

Comment: How did you determine `numRows` and `numColumns`?

Comment: Silly me. I was copying code from a website without checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way, please:

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(-3)).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    
    Set rngDB = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
    
    Set rngDB = rngDB.Resize(rngDB.Rows.Count - 3, rngDB.Columns.Count)
    
    rngDB.Select
End Sub
```

If cell a1 is a reference cell, it is as follows.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    
    Set rngDB = Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown))
    
    Set rngDB = rngDB.Resize(rngDB.Rows.Count - 3, rngDB.Columns.Count)
    
    rngDB.Select
End Sub
```